# Reflection EF .NET Core to get objects from database

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core

I have requirment to get the data from context object using reflection concept in EF .NET Core.
For Ex:

```
_context.TblClaim.Take(5).ToArray()
```

In the above line of code I Need to pass TblClaim using reflection, then I need to get the top 5 records, Please someone help me on this.
Note: If you need any info please let me know.

Comment: What is you are passing actually? Can you please show an example of parameters? Where requirement of using reflection comes from?

Comment: ```foreach (var propertyInfo in _context.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("DbSet")))
     {
      string tableName = "TblClaim";
      tableNames.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
      //var tbname = _context.Set(propertyInfo.Name).Take(5).ToList();
     }```
If you see the above code, I will all DbSet objects, then I need to get few records from each DbSet object